# Why can't I install Python 3.8?

Tags: command-line, python, versions

When I try to install Python 3.8 terminal says it is done, but when I run `python --version` it says Python 3.7.

```
(base) user@admin:~$ sudo apt-get install python3.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3.8 is already the newest version (3.8.2-1ubuntu1.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm9 libllvm9:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
```

```
(base) user@admin:~$ python --version
Python 3.7.6
```

Comment: The python 3.8 is most likely installed. You can verify it by running `which python3.8` which will print `/usr/bin/python3.8`. The `python` command You are running is just a symlink inside the `/usr/bin/` folder pointing to python 3.7.6

Comment: Oh! I see thanks! But so how can I connect Py3.8 to VScode. Because my vscode Python is on version 3.8 but I can't import any modules because of version different my terminal? Have any solutions for that ?

Comment: @BurakÇolak Please update Your question with what exactly are You trying to achieve.

Comment: what does (base) in front of your prompt status mean? are you installing it in a conda/python environment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the instructions on [How to Install Python 3.8 on Ubuntu, Debian and LinuxMint – TecAdmin](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-8-ubuntu/), try the following:

#### Prerequisites:

Install [and or update] the following packages; build-essential, checkinstall, libreadline-gplv2-dev, libncursesw5-dev, libssl-dev, libsqlite3-dev, tk-dev, libgdbm-dev, libc6-dev, libbz2-dev, libffi-dev, zlib1g-dev.

```
sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Thereafter, change directory (`cd`) to your `opt` folder [or any convenient folder] and download the python source code from python's server:

#### First change directory (cd) to the 'opt' folder:

```
cd /opt/
```

#### Download the source code

```
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tgz
```

#### Extract the [downloaded] source code files

```
sudo tar xzf Python-3.8.3.tgz
```

#### Change directory (`cd`) the Python Folder [created after the extraction]

```
cd Python-3.8.3
```

#### Compile the source code

```
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
```

then

```
sudo make altinstall
```

Once the compilation is completed, you can confirm that Python 3.8 has been installed successfully with:

```
python3.8 -V
```

You should see the response `Python-3.8.3`.

However, to precisely answer your question, python 3.8 isn't available via ubuntu official repos. You would have to add a PPA to get python 3.8 using `sudo apt install [python3.x.x]`.

The process is described on [How to Install Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 | Linuxize](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Hope this helps and I hope I answered your question adequately.

Comment: *python 3.8 isn't available via ubuntu official repos:* As per [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3.8&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), Python 3.8 is **available** for all versions starting from 18.04. Also, I use 20.04 as my primary installation and Python 3.8 is the default Python 3 in that. See [release notes of Focal Fossa](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Python3_by_default).

Comment: libreadline-gplv2-dev seems obsoleted. libreadline-dev is installed though.

Comment: @harryghgim hi, Just a brief couple of questions:  Did you get a chance to try to continue with the compilation and installation? If so, how did it go [was it successful]?

Comment: @Alvindera97 It was a while ago, so I might remember incorrectly. I did compile it after installing packages. During compilation readline related tasks was unsuccessful, so I googled and installed other readline package. It worked after that.

Comment: @harryghgim alright, thanks ✌

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Python 3.8 is already installed but not set as default.
Python 3.7.6 is set as default.

Update default Python3 version by below command.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Choose Python 3.8 option and check Python version again.

Comment: I assume OP is using 20.04 (since 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.2 is available in Focal as per [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3.8&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)). Python 3.8 is already set to be the default **`python3`**. Changing it would have made many applications to behave abnormally. As per the question, it seems they made `python` a symlink/alias to 3.7. So, they need to update alternatives for **`python`**. Moreover, AFAIK, alternatives for Python and Python 3 aren't "installed" to be configured by default.  You might need to `-install` them first.